# How to use single button to carry out different actions on different panels?

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

I'm making a panel to display a property advertisement with "Buy" and "Favorite" buttons at the bottom. Instead of making same panels multiple times, I've created a method that produces an advertisement panel for me and I simply call the method multiple times with different co-ordinate.

```
public JPanel createAdvertisement(int price, String owner, String location, int bedrooms, int bathrooms,
        int stories, int area) {
    JPanel adPanel = new JPanel();
    adPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    adPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    adPanel.setBounds(50, 138, 500, 230);
    this.add(adPanel);
    adPanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel housePicture = new JLabel("");
    housePicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/stock house.jpg")));
    housePicture.setBounds(10, 0, 194, 200);
    adPanel.add(housePicture);

    JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(price));
    priceLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    priceLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/price.png")));
    priceLabel.setBounds(214, 11, 276, 32);
    adPanel.add(priceLabel);

    JLabel ownerLabel = new JLabel(owner);
    ownerLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/owner.png")));
    ownerLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    ownerLabel.setBounds(218, 50, 270, 21);
    adPanel.add(ownerLabel);

    JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel("<html>" + location + "</html>");
    locationLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/location.png")));
    locationLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    locationLabel.setBounds(220, 75, 270, 30);
    adPanel.add(locationLabel);

    JLabel bedroomLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(bedrooms) + " Rooms");
    bedroomLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/bedroom.png")));
    bedroomLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    bedroomLabel.setBounds(224, 118, 100, 21);
    adPanel.add(bedroomLabel);

    JLabel bathroomLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(bathrooms) + " Baths");
    bathroomLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/bathroom.png")));
    bathroomLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    bathroomLabel.setBounds(350, 118, 100, 21);
    adPanel.add(bathroomLabel);

    JLabel storiesLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(stories) + " Stories");
    storiesLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/floors.png")));
    storiesLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    storiesLabel.setBounds(224, 150, 100, 21);
    adPanel.add(storiesLabel);

    JLabel areaLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(area) + " Marla");
    areaLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BrowseAds.class.getResource("/images/area.png")));
    areaLabel.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    areaLabel.setBounds(350, 150, 100, 21);
    adPanel.add(areaLabel);

    buyButton = new JButton("Buy");
    buyButton.addActionListener(this);
    buyButton.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    buyButton.setBounds(214, 196, 120, 23);
    adPanel.add(buyButton);

    JButton btnAddToFavorite = new JButton("Add to Favorite");
    btnAddToFavorite.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    btnAddToFavorite.setBounds(360, 196, 120, 23);
    adPanel.add(btnAddToFavorite);

    return adPanel;
}
```

I want to call different methods on the same button based on its location. E.g. If the user clicks the 3rd "Buy" button on the screen, I want to send the data of that advertisement to the back-end. Can you suggest me a way to carry different actions using the same button.

The code for making advertisements:

```
public void viewAds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int index = ((pageNumber - 1) * 4) + i;
        if (index < totalCount) {
            Ad curr = array.get(i);
            JPanel panel = createAdvertisement(curr.price, curr.owner, curr.location, curr.bedrooms, curr.bathrooms,
                    curr.stories, curr.area);
            if (index % 4 == 0) {
                panel.setBounds(70, 138, 500, 230);
            }
            if (index % 4 == 1) {
                panel.setBounds(700, 138, 500, 230);
            }
            if (index % 4 == 2) {
                panel.setBounds(70, 380, 500, 230);
            } else if (index % 4 == 3) {
                panel.setBounds(700, 380, 500, 230);
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Work it out with one or two buttons first, and leave out the icons unless that affects the problem. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SExtend JButton to include a field private or otherwise that records which one it is.  All that is needed is an ID.  Going further than that is a form of caching or it might be better to have a component/container that keeps info, for example coords on screen.

```
class SButton extends JButton {

    int myID;

    // Code that accepts an ActionListener and applies it to this button.
    // Or use super classes' methods and constructors.

    // Constructor has to set the button's command to include the ID
    // The ID can be generated statically in sequence or provide by
    // outside code.  This is because the command is passed through
    // the ActionEvent generated by the thread.  So a simple way
    // is to append the ID at the end of the command.  This can
    // be easy because the SButtons will all have the same label
    // or you can provide a single base for their command for all.

}


class Ad {

    Point myLocation;

    // Ad code creates panel that uses an SButton, maybe providing ID.

}

class AdManager implements ActionListener {

    Ad [] myAds = new Ad []; // use lists, hashmaps, etc. as appropriate.

    void initAds () {
        for (some kind of loop) {
            make some kind of Ad;
            set its ActionListener to this AdManager;
            put it in myAds;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand ();
        int anID = cmd.subString (some index at the end);
        theOneMethodThatSyedWroteThatHandlesAllTheSButtons (anID);
    }
}
```

Comment: `class SButton extends JButton {` I would be astonished if there was no better way to achieve this..

Comment: I would be similarly astonished and eager to know it.  Sometimes though, especially for new learners with questions, complex though elegant approaches can be confusing.  Thus "better" would need to be defined; some other factors might be efficiency, code space, data storage, maintainability, reusability, extensibility, and other stuff you can think of.

Comment: @Syed, Andrew is invoking a good guiding principle to avoid extending Swing components unless one is really adding functionality.  In this case an ID would be extra functionality.  One could use the actual reference to each Button as an ID as a way to avoid extending JButton but that might be a bit more involved and is brittle if the references are changed if the Buttons or Ads are recreated so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't have the knowledge of extending the GUI components so I'm gonna take a different approach. Maybe creating 4 different buttons would be a par for me. Thanks for the help anyways. Your help is appreciated.